# command line argument in c++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

i am trying to use command line argument in Linux(Ubuntu) in c++ . but it generates run time error : segmentation fault.this program runs with no error in windows .here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc , char **argv){
char **ss;
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
ss[i] = argv[i];

}
for(int i=0;i<argc ;i++)
cout<<ss[i];
return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with this code. please help me . thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take the habit to compile with all warnings and debug info (i.e. `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Your program has undefined behaviour because you did not initialize pointer `ss` and allocate memory where you are going to copy elements pointed by argv

```
char **ss;   // What value does it have?
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
ss[i] = argv[i];
```

You could do the following way

```
char **ss = new char *[argc];   
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
ss[i] = argv[i];
```

The better way is to use `std::vector<std::string>`. In this case you could also copy not only pointers to arguments but and also the arguments. For example

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
   std::vector<std::string> v( argv, argv + argc );

   for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

If your compiler does not support the range based for statement then you can substitute it for

```
   for ( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) 
   { 
      std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, you haven't allocated any memory for `ss`.
Since you're using c++ and not c, you should have the c++ standard library at your disposal:

```
std::vector<std::string> ss;
ss.reserve(argc); // not necessary
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    ss.push_back(argv[i]);
```

Comment: +1, but there's a much simpler alternative: `std::vector<std::string> ss(argv, argv + argc);`

Comment: Probably a bit less readable for c++ programmers without c background and thus unfamiliar with pointer arithmetic, but very concise indeed. I'll keep that in mind for when I have need to convert raw arrays in my own code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following declaration for ss

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc , char **argv){
    char *ss[argc]; // <--allocate argc count of pointers
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
        ss[i] = argv[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<argc ;i++)
        cout<<ss[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not C++ compliant. There is no VLA in C++.